# How to fix additional margins under single line text (in Firefox only)?

Tags: css, firefox, margin

I have a table with a cell in it that just contains text. This cell and its parent `tr` and `table` tags have no styles applied on them apart from [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), `vertical-align: top` on the `td` & `tr` and `border-bottom: 1px solid black` to make the problem clear for you to see. If there's only one line of text inside the cell, Firefox adds some additional margin that I do not want.

[image: margin in Firefox]

In Chrome this is not the case.

(How) can I fix this in Firefox without messing it up in Chrome?

Comment: Can you provide us with a fiddle? I can't seem to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fixed it. I changed the `vertical-align: baseline` to `vertical-align:top` in my copy of reset.css, then it worked, even though it's overwritten in my own stylesheet for the `td` tag and its parent `tr` tag (forgot to include this information in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the issue by changing the `vertical-align` on all the items in my copy of reset.css from `baseline` to `top`. It seems that this is necessary even if the `td` and `tr` tags already have their `vertical-align` set to `top`.